# How to get best magento performance on server?

Tags: magento-1.8

I need to know to speed up Magento performance on server what should be minimum requirement.

In my case there is about 1,00,000 products that will be imported from Microsoft Dynamic NAV.

I want to know about best configuration for To get great performance from magento.

i am not going to host it on Shared hosting as it is B2B system with heavy db. i preferred other options that you suggest

I you have any idea regarding to this please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best configuration for Magento servers:

1. PHP >= 5.4
2. Flat catalog (if this is possible)
3. nginx + php5-fpm
4. opcache/apc
5. Percona for database
6. Redis for session
7. Varnish
8. Solr for search (build in enterprise)

http://magentotherightway.com/ here you can find some useful informations ;) 
[Here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/whitepaper/) You have some informations on official Magento whitepapers.

For server You can choose some cloud environments (for example Amazon EC2), than if you need more power for particular moment (e.g. Easter) you can scale whole environment. Another good practice is separating the application and database servers.